# MD Construction Doesn't Propagate TCR

Tags: collision-resistance

I'm reading a proof of the proposition of [CollisionResistant Hashing Towards Making UOWHFs Practical](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/tcr-hash.pdf)

> Suppose there exists a compression function $F: \Sigma^k\times\Sigma^{c+m'} \rightarrow \Sigma^c$ with $m'>k$ such that $F$ is $(t',\epsilon')$-resistant to target collisions. Then there exists a compression function $H$ such that $H$ is $(t,\epsilon)$-resistant to target collisions for $t=t'- \Theta (k+m') $ and $\epsilon' = \epsilon + 2^{-k+1}$

To show that, the author constructs the following hash function:
$$H(K,x||y||z) = H_K(x||y||z)=
\begin{cases}
  F_K(x||y||z)||K & \text{if }y\neq K
\\1^c||1^k & \text{if }y = K
\end{cases}$$

Here is the proof:

> [image: Blockquote]

My questions:

- I don't understand why a $CF'$ run in time $t+O(k+c+m)$ I know why he add $t$ but I don't undertand Why $O(k+c+m)$?
- Why a $ProbSuccess(CF',F)\geq 1-2^{-k+1}$? I understand that means $2^{-k}$ but I don't Why $2^{-k}*2$

Comment: @jauninf- I've suggested a couple of minor edits for clarity (writing the hash function in cases, - into bullets), hope they're helpful